# Using cron or something else?

Tags: php, codeigniter, cron

I need to make an app where admin will add football match.

Then, these matches will show up on a home page and will be added before match is going to start of course.
Now, if he adds it in 17:15, and match starts in 20:45, I need it to have label match started and I will then disable it or remove it from page.

I'm using codeigniter php framework, I don't see they have something useful for cron jobs. Is using cron way to go in this case?  I will probably need to use php native cron functions

Any advice appreciated

Comment: What do you need a cron job for?  Why don't you just have the page display "match started" if it's past the known match time?

Comment: oh, so I guess I could just refer to current time in this case. I had in mind that I have to do more things. thanks ;)

Answer (score 2):

I don't see what cron could possibly do here, except maybe cleanup old database entries periodically.

All you need to do, is check the current time with the start time in your database.

Answer (score 2):

cron is for server side where you need to perform sceduled tasks , cron displays nothing on front end of your application, you might need periodic calls to your script which then check whatever you want to check from database

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
setTimeout( function() {
        // here you can call any javascript function which will access your script through ajax call
}, 1000 );
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need a cron job for this. PHP will evaluate code and construct your page every time a user requests it, so you can make sure that the appropriate matches for that exact time are displayed. You would just build your page around a query that selects matches where the ending time is later than the current time.